# Function able to accept super type?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I have this scala3 code:

```
val times4 = List.fill(4)
val oranges = times4("orange")
println(oranges)
```

Output is:

> List(orange, orange, orange, orange)

But, is this correct behaviour? Because intellij tells me times4 is:

> Nothing => List[Nothing]

But it is able to accept String type, while String is not a Nothing

Comment: I don't know what IntelliJ tells you, but Scala 3.1.2 tells me that the type of `List.fill(4)` is `(=> Any) => List[Any]`, and `"orange"` is certainly an `Any`. Submit a bug to intelliJ, if you want, that's not a Scala 3 problem.

Comment: It happens also in Scala 2.13.x. This is the output from the console of sbt `val times4 = List.fill(4) _
val times4: (=> Nothing) => List[Nothing] = $Lambda$13581/0x000000080161c400@2ba2e103`